# How to convert "plain TeX" to LaTeX

Tags: plain-tex

I want to convert to LaTeX  from plain TeX. 
I try use Emacs, but I can't. The document is [this](https://raw.github.com/yyr/org-mode/master/doc/orgcard.tex).

Comment: If it is just one fixed document, why do you want to convert it? why not just process it with plain?

Comment: You've accepted the answer, thanks but I'm still interested as to why you would want to do that, if you have latex you must have plain as well?

Comment: I want to use Lyx to import a document, but Lyx only work with latex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to work, it might need some slight tweaks, but produces a three column layout basically like the original.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{plain}
\usepackage{pdflayout}
\begin{document}
\begin{plain}
\makeatletter
\def\pagebody{\vbox to\vsize{\boxmaxdepth\maxdepth \pagecontents}}
\def\pagecontents{\dimen@=\dp\@cclv \unvbox\@cclv}
\def\makeheadline{\vbox to\z@{\vskip-22.5\p@
  \line{\vbox to8.5\p@{}\the\headline}\vss}\nointerlineskip}
\def\makefootline{\baselineskip24\p@\lineskiplimit\z@\line{\the\footline}}
\newtoks\headline \headline={\hfil}
\newtoks\footline \footline={\hss\rm\thepage\hss}
\def\input #1 {}
\makeatother
\csname @@input\endcsname orgcard
\end{plain}
\end{document}
```