# Conversion of tex to latex

Tags: tex-core, conversion, plain-tex

Quite surprisingly for me, I did not find valuable information on how to convert plain TeX files to LaTeX documents. There is a TeX.SX [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108733/how-to-convert-plain-tex-to-latex), but it was answered with a particular solution.

I have a larger number of simple TeX files with equations which I would like to convert to LaTeX articles. The need arises because I want to merge the documents with others which are based on LaTeX. The files do not contain any images and no complicated layouts.

Is there a simple but stable conversion tool somewhere out there which helps me to achieve this?

There seems to be a tool called `tex2latex` but I only found a windows binary. I work on Ubuntu and my LaTeX distribution is TeX Live.

Comment: As TeX is Turing-complete, your input could in principle contain anything: that's a challenge for a general tool! We probably need some example of how your input typically looks to make helpful suggestions for your case.

Comment: Did you take a look on [`plain.sty`](http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/macros/latex/contrib/carlisle/plain.sty)? It allows you to write `\begin{plain}\input{plain-doc}\end{plain}`. Could be handy if you really just want to include some equations or alike.

Comment: You can try to process it by LaTeX. Many things from plain TeX surprisingly work in LaTeX. Especially the math. If there is some problem you can solve it on the fly.

Comment: Yes, I know. However the tex part (the formulas) would look quite differently if I do this. The tool should convert at least tex equations to equation environments, `\over` to `\frac` etc ... @ChrisS thanks for the edit. @LaRiFaRi no I did not, but I will.

Comment: `{a\over b}` gives the same result as `\frac ab`. I don't understand why you need to convert `\over` to `\frac`.

Comment: @wipet Not necessarily; `\frac` is defined as `{\begingroup#1\endgroup\over#2}` for a reason.

Comment: In my experience, converting a well written Plain TeX file to LaTeX is easier than converting bad LaTeX to proper coding. For instance, `{\rm A}` should become `\mathrm{A}` and it's not difficult to do the change with regular expressions; also `$a\over b$` should become `$\frac{a}{b}$`, while `{a\over b}` becomes `\frac{a}{b}`; nested braces can give problems, of course.

Comment: @egreg But `{a\over b}` gives the same result as `\frac ab`. The notations of type `{\rm a\over b}` in plain TeX are very rare and they should be converted to the LaTeX `\frac` as `\frac{\rm a}{\rm b}` or `\frac{\mathrm{a}}{\mathrm{b}}` or similar. And the best: leave `\over` as `\over`.

Comment: @wipet I saw several instances of (pseudo) Plain TeX/LaTeX with much worse input than `{\rm a\over b}`. Simply don't trust users will code in a straightforward way.

Comment: I think there are several examples which would trigger such discussion and that this supports my question for a tool which performs these replacements.

Comment: @highsciguy I don't think a tool is possible in general (to parse arbitrary definitions and recode them in a more latex-like way) it may be possible to spot simple idioms such as {a \over b} and change to \frac but in general this won't be possible and for the other cases really the safe thing to do is leave them as they are.

Comment: @highsciguy a general tool would take a plain tex document such as [this](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/plain/contrib/xii/xii.tex) and convert it to more idiomatic latex use.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It does not need to be really general. A collection of regular expressions which performs the most common conversions would already be a great help. I see here that others have done such conversions before and they could be available as a script. Ideally it would be stable in the sense that it does not destroy valid tex input.

Comment: @highsciguy honestly, I wouldn't do it. regexp replacements in general _will_ destroy valid tex input. For specific documents with a naturally limited range of idioms it may be worth just doing a query-replace "by hand" in an editor but a general scripted solution has a high probability of breaking documents for essentially no functional gain (since it is easy to make the plain tex markup work in latex, which is what `plain` package does)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{plain}
\begin{document}
\begin{plain}
\input{texfile}
\end{plain}
\end{document}
```

Comment: couldn't be simpler could it? of course a DPC package :-)

Comment: I tried a bit and found that I can apparently use also latex code in the `plain` environment. Is there a restriction to this? I am asking because the goal is to merge rather than to concatenate tex and latex files. This means that I want e.g. to take a tex equation and combine it with a latex equation.

Comment: Generally packages only add functionality.  There might be a problem if a macro name means one thing in plain TeX and another in LaTeX.  Note that environments and counters are actually implemented using macros and counts.  For example, \equation  \endequation and \c@page

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty, at least with using regexes on a non regular language, is perhaps best seen via an example. Given a command `\eqalignno`, one could perhaps try a multiline match with, say, awk: `/\\eqalignno\{/, /^ +\}$/ { do_something }` (match for a range, starting with the pattern inside the first `//`, and continue on until finding the second pattern.

But already you can see that it relies on the source file being formatted in a specific way; the latter pattern expects the closing brace to be on a line of its own (with possible preceding whitespace).

The reason I started to answer was that I started to work on such regexes for this question, and while I got the matcher working on one of my files, in the very second one I had used instead: `\eqalign{\n ...\cr ...\n }$$\n`. Well okay, you just include a test for the presence of those closing display math dollars, right? So the latter pattern would become `/^ +\}(\$\$)?$/`.

But wait, in the next file I had used `...\cr}$$\n` instead. And yet in another file, `...\n  }$$ ...\n`!

This reminded me of a [previous Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/280304), and so would like to close with the words: *The `\center` cannot hold it is too late*.

Comment: I think for this kind of problem I have the solution (I use it routinely to parse latex commands). It is balanced pattern matching. In perl: `my $np;
  $np = qr{
          \{
          (?:
              (?> [^\{\}]+ ) 
            |
              (??{ $np }) )*
          \}
        }x;`. However that is complicated by the fact that not all tex command have the form `\eqalignno{..{}..}..{..}` For example `\over` is different.

Comment: @highsciguy: Yeah, and for the above you'd need to differentiate between `\{`/`\}` and `{`/`}`, etc. etc.

Comment: As long as `\{` and `\}`, this would still be easy. If they are unmatched?

Comment: @highsciguy: actually, yeah, I think you're right. So at the moment my answer is misleading; I'll update it once I get the hang of recursive named groups.

Comment: @highsciguy: I'm sorry I just can't get sub capture groups to work; this is what I've tried in ruby: `@texregexp = /\\(?<macro>[[:alpha:]]+\s*(?<args>(?!\\)\{(\g<macro>|[^{}])*\}))/m` (testing with `a_string.scan @texregexp`)

Comment: For perl, I had asked another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26174629/enhancing-perl-regular-expression-for-balanced-matching/26174871?noredirect=1#comment41038960_26174871 . The answer parses reliably balanced curly brackets which possibly contain escaped curly brackets.