# Convert Plain TeX automatic table generation macros to LaTex

Tags: macros, plain-tex

I have written code, given at at the end of the post, to typeset exams and quizzes in plain TeX.

A typical test would be typeset using:

```
\def\CLASS{Math 111}
\def\TERM{Spring 2015}
\def\TITLE{Quiz 3}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\input examformat
\def\folio{} 
\TestFormat
\HMarkbox
\def\ve{\vfill\eject}
\HowWide{\bf 22.}% space provided for problem numbers
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\heading{\CLASS}{\TERM}{\TITLE}{}
\instructs{\bf  This is a closed book, closed notes quiz. 
To receive full credit for a problem,
your solutions must be complete, well-organized,  and grammatically correct.
Partial credit will be given when merited.}

\problem{10}   A farmer has $200$ feet of fence and wishes to construct a pen adjacent to a river. The side of the pen along the river requires no fence. ...

\ep

\problem{20}
Hello!
\ep

\problem{10}
A really long problem
\ve

blah
\ep

\problem{10} Last problem.

\ep
\bye
```

which produces the following:

[image]

The Mark Box and problem numbers are generated automatically. Each `\problem{#1}` adds the problem number and value (`#1`) as a column of the Mark box.
This is done by saving the first page of the document in a box and typesetting it last, after all the problem values are known. This is accomplished by redefining Plain Tex's output routine and `\end` command.

Also, if a problem is broken across pages, this is indicated in the footlines and headlines of the pages.

I wish to to do the same thing in LaTeX. I'm new to LaTeX, and would appreciate any advice on how to do so.  Is there an easy way to do this using built in functions in LaTeX?
(I'm more concerned with automatically generating the Mark box, rather than the "continued lines".)

For those daring enough to decipher my, functional but likely horrendous, code below: can I make it work using LaTeX without much modification?

Here is the plain Tex code (which is the contents of the file "examformat" in the first code block above):

```
\catcode`\!=11               
\catcode`\@=11
\def\nskp{\nointerlineskip}      \def\ts{\textstyle}   \def\ds{\displaystyle}
\def\ss{\scriptstyle}            \def\sss{\scriptscriptstyle}        
\def\TF{{\bf T\thinspace F}}     \def\DSP#1{$\ds{#1}$}
\def\INC#1{\advance#1by1 }       \def\Z@{0 pt}     \def\B!gPen{\penalty10000 }
\def\arcsec{\mathop{\rm arcsec}\nolimits}
\def\date{\ifcase\month\or 
    January\or February\or March\or April\or May\or June\or July\or August
    \or September\or October\or November\or December\fi\space\number\day}
\def\blank#1{\underbar{\phantom{\hskip#1}}}  
\def\name{{\bf NAME\thinspace}\blank{2.4 true in}}
\newif\ifbk!
\def\RmveDscrdItems{{\bk!true
    \ifvmode \ifinner \else \let\unpenalty=\relax\let\unkern=\relax \fi \fi
    \loop \unskip\unpenalty\unkern\unskip\unpenalty\unkern   
    \ifbk! \ifdim\lastskip=0.0pt \ifdim\lastkern=0.0pt \ifnum\lastpenalty=0 
           \bk!false \fi \fi \fi
    \repeat \unskip\unpenalty\unkern \bk!true}}
%
%  List/token manipulatuion routines
%  See The TeXboox, pg. 378-379
%
\toksdef\ta=0 \toksdef\tb=2 % 
\long\def\rightappend#1\to#2{\ta={\\{#1}}\tb=\expandafter{#2}%
         \edef#2{\the\tb\the\ta}} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 \font\eightrm=cmr8   
\def\Ntopskip{10pt}  
%   Fonts
% 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%         formating routines
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newdimen\keyw!dth    
\edef\HowWide#1{{\setbox0\hbox{#1}\global\keyw!dth\wd0}\ignorespaces}    
\def\ccont{\hbox{\vtop{\offinterlineskip
    \hbox{\sevenrm continued}\vskip1pt\hbox to 45 pt{\rightarrowfill}}}}
\def\ccontl{\hbox{\vtop{\offinterlineskip\hbox to 45 pt
    {\hfil\sevenrm cont. from}\vskip1pt\hbox to 45 pt{\leftarrowfill}}}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%
%  Format a test/problem sheet. Insert ``continued lines''.
%
%
\newif\ifT!tleP@ge   \newif\ifF!T!TM    \newif\ifM@rkBox
\newif\ifPr@@b       \newif\ifFP@       \newif\ifT@stFMT
\newbox\PB@x         \newbox\He@dBox    \newbox\M@rkBox
\newbox\F!rstP@ge    \newbox\!nstruct!onBox
\newskip\ITEMSKIP    \newcount\Pr@blemNumber
\newdimen\IT@        \newdimen\IT@@
\def\TestFormat{\@@false\T@stFMTtrue\T!tleP@gefalse\M@rkBoxfalse\Pr@blemNumber0 
    \ITEMSKIP4pt\hsize6.5 true in\vsize9.0 true in\parindent0pt \parskip1pt
    \raggedbottom\postdisplaypenalty1
    \output{\plainoutput}%
    \footline{\hfill\tenrm\folio\hfill\if y\botmark\rlap{\ccont}\fi}
    \headline{\if y\topmark\llap{\ccontl}\fi\hfill}
        \def\MarkBoxAdjust{0pt}
    \def\problem{%
        \ifPr@@b\errmessage{Missing \noexpand\ep.}\fi
        \ifvmode
           \ifinner\errmessage{\noexpand\problem not allowed in inner mode.}%
           \else\SetProbl@m
           \fi
        \else\errmessage{\noexpand\problem not allowed outside vertical mode.}%
        \fi}
    \def\heading##1##2##3##4{\topskip\Z@ \topglue.5in  
        \ulap{\vbox to1in{\vfil\hbox to\hsize{\bf ##1\hfil\bf ##2}\kern8pt
                 \hbox to\hsize{\bf ##3\hfil\bf ##4}\vfil}}\hrule\vglue6pt}%
    \def\instructs##1{\leavevmode\vskip10pt{\bf ##1}\vskip10pt}
    \let\@ND=\end\def\end{{\if@@\@NDT\aftergroup\@ND\else\aftergroup\@ND\fi}}}
\def\SetProbl@m{\Pr@@btrue\F!T!TMtrue\global\advance\Pr@blemNumber1 
    \vskip18pt plus10pt minus12pt 
    \setbox\PB@x\vbox\bgroup\noindent
           \llap{\rlap{\bf\the\Pr@blemNumber.}\hskip\keyw!dth}\indent
                 \vadjust{\mark{y}\B!gPen}\ignorespaces}
\newhelp\EXTR@EP{You have an extra \string\ep. This \string\ep\space will be ignored.}
\def\@RR@R#1#2{\errhelp=#1\errmessage{#2}}
\def\ep{%
    \ifPr@@b\global\Pr@@bfalse\par\RmveDscrdItems\mark{n}\egroup\unvbox\PB@x
    \else\@RR@R\EXTR@EP{Extra \string\ep}% 
    \fi}
%
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%
%  Titlepage/markboxes
%
%
\newcount\!! \newcount\!j
 \def\ulap#1{\vbox to 0pt{\vss#1}}%
\newif\if@@
\def\HMarkbox{\@@true\m@rkbox\HMB@X\def\F@nt{\def\MB@F{\tenrm}\eightrm}}  
 \def\m@rkbox#1{\ifT@stFMT\else\errmessage{Missing \noexpand\TestFormat.}\fi
    \ifM@rkBox\errmessage{You can only have one markbox.}\fi
    \def\PL!ST{}\M@rkBoxtrue\let\Problem=\problem
    \def\problem##1{\ifnum##1=0 \fi\rightappend{##1}\to\PL!ST\Problem}%
    \def\M@kebox{\setbox\M@rkBox\vbox{#1\kern15pt}}% 
       \output{\F!rstOut}\topskip\Z@\topglue1in   
       \def\heading##1##2##3##4{%
           \setbox\He@dBox\vbox to 1.5in{\vfil\hbox{\bf##1, ##2\hfill}\kern8pt
                   \hbox{\bf##3\hfill}\kern8pt\hbox{\name \hfil}\kern15pt}}%
    }
\def\F!rstOut{\advancepageno
        \global\setbox\F!rstP@ge=\vbox to\vsize{\dimen@=\dp255 \unvbox255
        \ifr@ggedbottom \kern-\dimen@ \vfil \fi}%
        \if y\botmark \global\FP@true \else \global\FP@false \fi
        \global\output{\plainoutput}\global\topskip\Ntopskip}
\def\@NDT{%
       \ifM@rkBox 
          \vfill\eject\M@kebox\gdef\ccontl{}%
          \topskip0pt\topglue1 true in
          \ulap{\hbox to\hsize{\box\He@dBox\hfill\box\M@rkBox}}%
          \nskp\hrule\vskip-.4pt\vglue-1in\box\F!rstP@ge
          \ifFP@\mark{y}\fi \global\pageno=1 
       \fi}
\def\HMB@X{%     
    \vbox{\!!=\Pr@blemNumber \advance\!!\!!  \advance\!!1 
    \F@nt\tabskip=0pt\offinterlineskip\def\tablerule{\noalign{\hrule}}
    \halign{\strut##&\vrule width.8pt##&&##&\vrule width.8pt##\cr
            \tablerule
            \omit\global\!j=1 
              \gdef\\##1{&\hbox to2em{\hfil\the\!j\hfil}&\global\INC\!j}% 
              &height1ex&\multispan\!!&\cr
            &&\multispan\!!\hfil\MB@F Mark box\hfil&\cr
            \omit&height1ex&\multispan\!!&\cr
            \tablerule\tablerule   
            &&\kern.4em Problem\kern.4em&width.8pt\PL!ST\cr
            \tablerule
            &\gdef\\##1{&\hbox to2em{\hfil##1\hfil}&}%
                       &\kern.4em Points\kern.4em&width.8pt\PL!ST\cr
            \tablerule
            &\gdef\\##1{&\hbox to2em{\hfil}&}%
                       &\kern.4em Earned\kern.4em&width.8pt\PL!ST\cr
            \tablerule\tablerule 
            \omit&height1ex&\multispan\!!&\cr
            \omit&&\multispan\!!\kern.4em Perc. score:\hfill&\cr
            \omit&height1ex&\multispan\!!&\cr
       \tablerule}}}
%
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\catcode`\!=12
\catcode`\@=12  
\endinput
```

I hope the following makes the above understandable:

`\TestFormat` Sets up page dimension parameters and spacing which I find pleasing. It also sets the `\footline` and `\headline` to insert "continued" and "continued from" if a problem 
is broken across pages (this is kept track of by inserting top and bottom marks).  `\problem` is defined here
to just give appropriate error messages if need be, and to typeset the problem via `\SetProbl@m`.

`\Setprobl@m` advances the problem number by 1 and typesets what's in between "`\problem(#1)`" and the first "`\ep`" afterwards. It and `\ep` also insert top and bottom marks as needed for the "continued lines".

`\HMarkbox` calls `\m@rkbox` with the argument `\HMB@x`.

`\m@rkbox` then defines a macro `\M@kebox` that, when expanded, will typeset the header, and typeset the Mark box using the macro `\HMB@x`. 
The actual Mark box is a table generated by `\halign` when `\HMB@x` is expanded using the contents of the token list `\PL!st`.   `\PL!st` is generated 
by the arguments to the `\problem`'s in the document (Each `\problem{#1}` in the document adds `#1` to the list `\PL!st`).

`\m@rkbox`  redefines the  output routine to `\F!rstOut`. When the first page is ready, `\F!rstout` copies the page contents to the box `\F!rstP@ge`, typesets nothing, and sets 
the output routine to `\plainoutput` (the default in plain TeX).

The plain TeX `\end` command is redefined. When invoked, it expands `\@NDT`, which expands `\M@kebox` and unboxes the `\F!rstP@ge`. Then it ends the document properly.

Comment: Why don't you use the plain package?  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203703/conversion-of-tex-to-latex/203730#203730